# What is the meaning and issue in this SQL program in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the meaning of this query and the underlying issue in it. Is there lack of clarity between primary and foreign keys among the tables here?

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ua1.given_name,
            (
                SELECT
                    count(*)
                FROM
                    portfolio_project_collaborator ppc1
                    INNER JOIN portfolio_project pp1 ON ppc1.portfolio_project_id = pp1.id
                WHERE
                    pp1.user_account_id = ua1.id
                    AND ppc1.approved_at IS NOT NULL) + (
                    SELECT
                        count(*)
                    FROM
                        productized_service_collaborator psc1
                        INNER JOIN productized_service ps1 ON psc1.productized_service_id = ps1.id
                    WHERE
                        ps1.user_account_id = ua1.id
                        AND psc1.approved_at IS NOT NULL) total_confirmed_collaborators
                FROM
                    user_account ua1
                WHERE (ua1.given_name <-> 'mike') < 1) t1
    ORDER BY
        t1.total_confirmed_collaborators DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What's your goal from the execution of the query? What does it return right now? What's your data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little formatting can sometimes help:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
           SELECT ua1.given_name
                , (
                      SELECT count(*)
                        FROM portfolio_project_collaborator ppc1
                        JOIN portfolio_project pp1 ON ppc1.portfolio_project_id = pp1.id
                       WHERE pp1.user_account_id = ua1.id
                         AND ppc1.approved_at IS NOT NULL
                  ) + (
                      SELECT count(*)
                        FROM productized_service_collaborator psc1
                        JOIN productized_service ps1 ON psc1.productized_service_id = ps1.id
                       WHERE ps1.user_account_id = ua1.id
                         AND psc1.approved_at IS NOT NULL
                  ) total_confirmed_collaborators
             FROM user_account ua1
            WHERE (ua1.given_name <-> 'mike') < 1
       ) t1
 ORDER BY t1.total_confirmed_collaborators DESC
 LIMIT 10
;
```

With formatting the meaning is a little clearer.

For each `user_account ua1` which meets the name criteria `(ua1.given_name <-> 'mike') < 1`, find the top 10 `total_confirmed_collaborators`.

The `total_confirmed_collaborators` is determined by adding these two terms per `user_account`:

```
 SELECT pp1.user_account_id, count(*)
   FROM portfolio_project_collaborator ppc1
   JOIN portfolio_project pp1 ON ppc1.portfolio_project_id = pp1.id
  WHERE ppc1.approved_at IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY pp1.user_account_id
 ;
```

```
 SELECT ps1.user_account_id, count(*)
   FROM productized_service_collaborator psc1
   JOIN productized_service ps1 ON psc1.productized_service_id = ps1.id
  WHERE psc1.approved_at IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ps1.user_account_id
;
```

Comment: I have the same understanding. Do you find any error here? like, conflict with primary key and foreign keys?

Comment: @EricGideon Could you update the question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statements with constraints?  I could guess at the structure / constraints.  Having that detail would be best.  The basic structure of the SQL seems fine, apart from having tables that might be refactored slightly to avoid the separate counts.

Comment: Sorry. I see the question is closed.   You might ask a different question with that structure / schema detail.  I'm not sure what particular behavior you think is the result of an error in the SQL.